# Обработка русских символов в Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

в моем проекте с последовательного порта я записываю входящие символы в массив, латинские символы обрабатываются хорошо, но когда я пытаюсь обработать русский символ, программа не работает. Здесь я пытаюсь обработать русский символ "П", и условие не выполняется, если я проверяю английские буквы, то все в порядке, как я могу решить проблему?

```
if(Text[3] == 'П')
      {
        Serial.println("Буква: П");
      }
```

Массив Text[] имеет тип char

Как выяснил редактор использует кодировку UTF-8

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
 char  text[] = "П";
 Serial.println(text);
  Serial.print("text length: "); 
 Serial.println(strlen(text));
 Serial.println(text[0], HEX);
 Serial.println(text[1], HEX);
}
void loop() 
{
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот мой главный вопрос как мне определить что пришла именно буква "П" с кодом D09F в шестнадцатеричном формате или 208 159 в десятеричном?

Answer (score 1):

Код символа "П" в вашем коде зависит от кодировки исходного файла.
Если вам нужно обрабатывать данные в однобайтной кодировке, можно сохранить исходный файл в той же кодировке.

Если нужно работать с многобайтной кодировкой, ищите библиотеки для работы с ней. Или изучайте стандарт utf8, и пытайтесь обрабатывать вручную. Для конкретных кодовых таблиц это возможно, но не советую.

Выбор кодировки зависит от прикладной задачи, а не от редактора. Если нужна информация о многобайтовых кодировках, задавайте отдельный вопрос.